# How do I merge rows of network traffic data flow pairs in R?

Tags: sql, r, network-traffic

I have lots of SiLK flow data that I would like to do some data mining on. It looks like the destination IP column matches the source IP column of a row of data further down. How do I merge the source id rows with the destination id rows in R? I have some simplified network traffic flow data for you:

```
id    sip    dip    notes
1     20     30     20 is talking to 30
2     20     31     20 is talking to 31
3     20     32     20 is talking to 32
4     30     20     30 is responding to 20
5     31     20     31 is responding to 20
6     32     20     32 is responding to 20
7     20     32     20 is talking to 32 again
8     20     30     20 is talking to 30 again
9     32     20     32 is responding to 20 again
10    20     31     20 is talking to 31 again
11    31     20     31 is responding to 20 again
12    30     20     30 is responding to 20 again
13    21     30     21 is talking to 30
14    30     21     30 is responding to 21
```

I want to merge the rows so that they look like this:

```
id_S    sip_S    dip_S    notes_S                      id_D    sip_D    dip_D    notes_D
1       20       30       20 is talking to 30          4       30       20       30 is responding to 20
2       20       31       20 is talking to 31          5       31       20       31 is responding to 20
3       20       32       20 is talking to 32          6       32       20       32 is responding to 20
7       20       32       20 is talking to 32 again    9       32       20       32 is responding to 20 again
8       20       30       20 is talking to 30 again    12      30       20       30 is responding to 20 again
10      20       31       20 is talking to 31 again    11      31       20       31 is responding to 20 again
13      21       30       21 is talking to 30          14      30       21       30 is responding to 21
```

I have more than a million rows of data. It takes days and lots of disk space to do it in SQL Express:

```
WITH flowtest_merged AS(
SELECT
    s.id AS id_S,
    s.sip AS sip_S,
    s.dip AS dip_S,
    s.notes AS notes_S,
    d.id AS id_D,
    d.sip AS sip_D,
    d.dip AS dip_D,
    d.notes AS notes_D,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY d.id) AS RN
FROM
    flowtest AS s INNER JOIN
    flowtest AS d ON
    s.dip = d.sip AND /* The source id is talking to the destination id */
    s.sip = d.dip AND /* The destination id is responding to the source id */
    s.id < d.id AND /* The source id is the initiator of the exchange */
    s.sip < 30 /* shorthand for "I'm selecting the internal ip range here" */
)
SELECT
    id_S,
    sip_S,
    dip_S,
    notes_S,
    id_D,
    sip_D,
    dip_D,
    notes_D
FROM flowtest_merged
WHERE (RN = 1)
```

The problem is, I don't know how to do the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY d.id) part. So, if I rebuild the example data frame in R:

```
> flowtest <- data.frame(
+     "id" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
+     "sip" = c(20, 20, 20, 30, 31, 32, 20, 20, 32, 20, 31, 30, 21, 30),
+     "dip" = c(30, 31, 32, 20, 20, 20, 32, 30, 20, 31, 20, 20, 30, 21),
+     "notes" = c(
+         "20 is talking to 30",
+         "20 is talking to 31",
+         "20 is talking to 32",
+         "30 is responding to 20",
+         "31 is responding to 20",
+         "32 is responding to 20",
+         "20 is talking to 32 again",
+         "20 is talking to 30 again",
+         "32 is responding to 20 again",
+         "20 is talking to 31 again",
+         "31 is responding to 20 again",
+         "30 is responding to 20 again",
+         "21 is talking to 30",
+         "30 is responding to 21"),
+     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So that it looks the same as the SQL data:

```
> flowtest
   id sip dip                        notes
1   1  20  30          20 is talking to 30
2   2  20  31          20 is talking to 31
3   3  20  32          20 is talking to 32
4   4  30  20       30 is responding to 20
5   5  31  20       31 is responding to 20
6   6  32  20       32 is responding to 20
7   7  20  32    20 is talking to 32 again
8   8  20  30    20 is talking to 30 again
9   9  32  20 32 is responding to 20 again
10 10  20  31    20 is talking to 31 again
11 11  31  20 31 is responding to 20 again
12 12  30  20 30 is responding to 20 again
13 13  21  30          21 is talking to 30
14 14  30  21       30 is responding to 21
```

When I make my feeble merger attempt:

```
> flowtest_merged <- merge(
+     flowtest[,setdiff(colnames(flowtest), "dip")],
+     flowtest[,setdiff(colnames(flowtest), "sip")],
+     by.x = "sip",
+     by.y = "dip",
+     all = FALSE,
+     suffixes = c("_S", "_D"))
```

It has many, many more rows (and the wrong columns):

```
> flowtest_merged
   sip id_S                      notes_S id_D                      notes_D
1   20    1          20 is talking to 30    5       31 is responding to 20
2   20    1          20 is talking to 30    6       32 is responding to 20
3   20    1          20 is talking to 30   11 31 is responding to 20 again
4   20    1          20 is talking to 30    4       30 is responding to 20
5   20    1          20 is talking to 30    9 32 is responding to 20 again
6   20    1          20 is talking to 30   12 30 is responding to 20 again
7   20    2          20 is talking to 31    5       31 is responding to 20
8   20    2          20 is talking to 31    6       32 is responding to 20
9   20    2          20 is talking to 31   11 31 is responding to 20 again
10  20    2          20 is talking to 31    4       30 is responding to 20
11  20    2          20 is talking to 31    9 32 is responding to 20 again
12  20    2          20 is talking to 31   12 30 is responding to 20 again
13  20    3          20 is talking to 32    5       31 is responding to 20
14  20    3          20 is talking to 32    6       32 is responding to 20
15  20    3          20 is talking to 32   11 31 is responding to 20 again
16  20    3          20 is talking to 32    4       30 is responding to 20
17  20    3          20 is talking to 32    9 32 is responding to 20 again
18  20    3          20 is talking to 32   12 30 is responding to 20 again
19  20    8    20 is talking to 30 again    5       31 is responding to 20
20  20    8    20 is talking to 30 again    6       32 is responding to 20
21  20    8    20 is talking to 30 again   11 31 is responding to 20 again
22  20    8    20 is talking to 30 again    4       30 is responding to 20
23  20    8    20 is talking to 30 again    9 32 is responding to 20 again
24  20    8    20 is talking to 30 again   12 30 is responding to 20 again
25  20   10    20 is talking to 31 again    5       31 is responding to 20
26  20   10    20 is talking to 31 again    6       32 is responding to 20
27  20   10    20 is talking to 31 again   11 31 is responding to 20 again
28  20   10    20 is talking to 31 again    4       30 is responding to 20
29  20   10    20 is talking to 31 again    9 32 is responding to 20 again
30  20   10    20 is talking to 31 again   12 30 is responding to 20 again
31  20    7    20 is talking to 32 again    5       31 is responding to 20
32  20    7    20 is talking to 32 again    6       32 is responding to 20
33  20    7    20 is talking to 32 again   11 31 is responding to 20 again
34  20    7    20 is talking to 32 again    4       30 is responding to 20
35  20    7    20 is talking to 32 again    9 32 is responding to 20 again
36  20    7    20 is talking to 32 again   12 30 is responding to 20 again
37  21   13          21 is talking to 30   14       30 is responding to 21
38  30    4       30 is responding to 20    1          20 is talking to 30
39  30    4       30 is responding to 20    8    20 is talking to 30 again
40  30    4       30 is responding to 20   13          21 is talking to 30
41  30   14       30 is responding to 21    1          20 is talking to 30
42  30   14       30 is responding to 21    8    20 is talking to 30 again
43  30   14       30 is responding to 21   13          21 is talking to 30
44  30   12 30 is responding to 20 again    1          20 is talking to 30
45  30   12 30 is responding to 20 again    8    20 is talking to 30 again
46  30   12 30 is responding to 20 again   13          21 is talking to 30
47  31    5       31 is responding to 20    2          20 is talking to 31
48  31    5       31 is responding to 20   10    20 is talking to 31 again
49  31   11 31 is responding to 20 again    2          20 is talking to 31
50  31   11 31 is responding to 20 again   10    20 is talking to 31 again
51  32    9 32 is responding to 20 again    3          20 is talking to 32
52  32    9 32 is responding to 20 again    7    20 is talking to 32 again
53  32    6       32 is responding to 20    3          20 is talking to 32
54  32    6       32 is responding to 20    7    20 is talking to 32 again
>
```

In other words, I'm not merging just one row with just one other row like I'd like to. How do I merge the source id row with just its destination id row?

Thanx

Dave

EDIT: Here's the first matching pair:

```
UID|SIP|DIP|PROTOCOL|SPORT|DPORT|PACKETS|BYTES|FLAGS|STIME|DURATION|ETIME|SENSOR|FLOWTYPE|ICMP_TYPE|ICMP_CODE|APPLICATION|INPUT|OUTPUT|TIMEOUT|CONTINUATION|INIT_FLAGS|SESSION_FLAGS|BLACKLIST|WHITELIST|NORMALIZED_DOMAIN|COUNTRY
720109425873|3232248427|3232248333|17|57554|53|1|70|0|2013-01-01 00:00:15.046|0|2013-01-01 00:00:15.046|THERMOPYLAE|6|||0|0|0|0|0|0|0|N|Y|erath.mechesrx.net|NULL
...
720107126014|3232248333|3232248427|17|53|57868|2|238|0|2013-01-01 00:02:15.827|0|2013-01-01 00:02:15.827|THERMOPYLAE|6|||0|0|0|0|0|0|0|N|Y|NULL|NULL
```

Comment: You can't use the notes field for anything - I made that field up for your edification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
#split your dataset in "talking"  and responding part
#this will need some seconds for several million entries
a <- data.table(df[grep('*talk*',df$notes),],key=c("sip","dip"))
b <- data.table(df[grep('*responding*',df$notes),],key=c("dip","sip"))
#create a second id for each couple
a[,id2:=seq_len(.N),by=key(a)]
b[,id2:=seq_len(.N),by=key(b)]

#merge
setnames(b,c("sip","dip"),c("dip","sip"))
merge(a,b,by=c("sip","dip","id2"),all=TRUE)

#    sip dip id2 id.x                   notes.x id.y                      notes.y
# 1:  20  30   1    1       20 is talking to 30    4       30 is responding to 20
# 2:  20  30   2    8 20 is talking to 30 again   12 30 is responding to 20 again
# 3:  20  31   1    2       20 is talking to 31    5       31 is responding to 20
# 4:  20  31   2   10 20 is talking to 31 again   11 31 is responding to 20 again
# 5:  20  32   1    3       20 is talking to 32    6       32 is responding to 20
# 6:  20  32   2    7 20 is talking to 32 again    9 32 is responding to 20 again
# 7:  21  30   1   13       21 is talking to 30   14       30 is responding to 21
```

If it's possible that one partner talks twice without the other responding, I am not sure how you want to handle that.

Comment: You can't go by what's in the notes field, that field was just put there for your edification.

Comment: @DaveBabbitt, is there any way in which the data can be split as Roland tried to do with your sample data here?

Comment: The only way you can tell they are pairs is the sip/dip switch happens a few seconds apart. But you can see perfect bilateral symmetry across the main diagonal if you plot a scatter graph of the two attributes, so you know its happening every time.

Comment: If you look at the SQL, you can see that I have an internal ip range that initiates the exchange. Sometimes, in the real data, they are just talking internally, but, instead of `a <- data.table(df[grep('*talk*',df$notes),],key=c("sip","dip"))` how about `a <- subset(df, df$SIP<30)` for the initiators? (I get `Error: could not find function "data.table"` when I try to use your example.) And then you could also have `b <- subset(df, df$DIP<30)` for the responders.

Comment: The error indicates that you did not load the package (first line of the code). You may have to first install it. Also, if you can separate initiators and responders by IP, you can do that. I must admit that the purpose of the whole exercise is not obvious to me.

Comment: Thanx. Now when I type in `a[,id2:=seq_len(.N),by=key(a)]` I get `Error in ``[.data.frame``(a, , ``:=``(id2, seq_len(.N)), by = key(a)) : unused argument (by = key(a))`

Comment: Your `a` is not a data.table, which it should be, if you made it one like I showed in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I see two reasons why you might be getting too many matching rows:

1. You have selected only `sip`/`dip` as matching criterion, while it should be (`sip, dip`)/(`dip, sip`). Use `by.x=c('sip', 'dip')` and the corresponding `by.y`.
2. The "talking" rows also match the "responding again" rows, and the "talking again" rows also match the "responding" rows. This is slightly more difficult to solve, let me introduce  `arrange(dataframe, ...)` from the `plyr` which sorts data frames elegantly.

Let's `arrange` your data so that related communications between the same peers are adjacent and assign IDs in this order.

```
library(plyr)
flowtest_arranged <- arrange(flowtest, pmin(sip, dip), pmax(sip, dip), id)
flowtest_arranged$nid <- seq_along(flowtest_arranged$id)
flowtest_arranged$nid.lag <- flowtest_arranged$nid - 1
```

Now, if we assume that your data is well behaved so that no unrelated communication appears between request and response, we can use the new `nid` variables as additional merge criterion: `by.x=c('sip', 'dip', 'nid.lag')`, `by.y=c('dip', 'sip', 'nid')`. Here's the result (R 3.0.1):

```
merge(flowtest_arranged, flowtest_arranged, by.x=c('sip', 'dip', 'nid.lag'),
      by.y=c('dip', 'sip', 'nid'))

   sip dip nid.lag id.x                      notes.x nid id.y
1   20  30       2    8    20 is talking to 30 again   3    4
2   20  31       6   10    20 is talking to 31 again   7    5
3   20  32      10    7    20 is talking to 32 again  11    6
4   30  20       1    4       30 is responding to 20   2    1
5   30  20       3   12 30 is responding to 20 again   4    8
6   30  21      13   14       30 is responding to 21  14   13
7   31  20       5    5       31 is responding to 20   6    2
8   31  20       7   11 31 is responding to 20 again   8   10
9   32  20      11    9 32 is responding to 20 again  12    7
10  32  20       9    6       32 is responding to 20  10    3
                     notes.y nid.lag
1     30 is responding to 20       1
2     31 is responding to 20       5
3     32 is responding to 20       9
4        20 is talking to 30       0
5  20 is talking to 30 again       2
6        21 is talking to 30      12
7        20 is talking to 31       4
8  20 is talking to 31 again       6
9  20 is talking to 32 again      10
10       20 is talking to 32       8
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(flowtest_arranged, flowtest_arranged, by.x = c("sip",  :
  column name ‘nid.lag’ is duplicated in the result
```

Comment: Have you tried `by.x=c('sip', 'dip')` on the flowtest data I provided? When I try, I get `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column`. The "R: Merge Two Data Frames" documentation shows the by.x and by.y arguments only taking one column as input.

Comment: @DaveBabbitt: I have, see my edit. What version of R are you using?

Comment: R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"